# If a large can is divided into smaller containers, is it still shelf stable?

Tags: food-safety, storage, vacuum

Everyone knows that buying in bulk usually saves money. My question involves buying and saving bulk canned veggies and items of that nature. Can you divide a bulk or industrial size can of say green beans or nacho cheese into mason jar, vacuum seal the jar with my Foodsaver and it still be shelf stable without traditional "canning"? I don't want my "nacho cheese" to go rancid on the shelf but I don't want it taking up valuable fridge space either.

Answer (score 8):

No. You can freeze items like that, and they will stay safe indefinitely in a fully functional freezer, but once you break the seal on the can, items like that are subject to same 2/4 hour shelf safety rules as any other cooked item.

See: [How do I know if food left at room temperature is still safe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat/34671#34671)

Comment: I'd add the caveat that not all items are suitable for freezing without suffering texture changes after thawing.

Comment: @KristinaLopez but if it's already been canned, it's unlikely to go through additional changes, as cooking and freezing generally have the same effect of breaking down the cell walls.

Answer (score 3):

No, it would not be safe to do so. You can divide it up and freeze it. That is the best and safest method. 
I would not, for the sake of safety and not making someone sick or worse, re-can anything without being an experienced canner. 
And even if you were an experienced canner, the time and cost involved would completely evaporate the amount of savings you made by buying in bulk. If you have any questions about canning in general though, please contact your local University Extension Service. They have information on USDA approved methods and cannning or otherwise preserving most foods.